# How to compare async function returned value

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I need help with comparing the returned value in async function. I always have "Promise {  }". I already tried different approaches with different results, but never what I need. This is the code that I have so far.

```
async function isType(username) {
    const result = await db.query('select * from users where username=?', [username])
    return await result[0].type;
}

module.exports = {
    isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated() && isType(req.user.username)==0) {
            return next();
        }
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
};
```

I also tried instead something like this:

```
isLoggedInAdmin(req, res, next) {
        isType(req.user.username).then(result => { 
            if (req.isAuthenticated() && result==0) {
                return next();
            }
        })

        return res.redirect('/');
    }
```

But in this case, the error is "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the `return res.redirect('/');` inside the `then` callback

```
isLoggedInAdmin(req, res, next) {
  isType(req.user.username).then(result => {
    if (req.isAuthenticated() && result == 0) {
      return next();
    }
    return res.redirect("/");
  });
}
```

Comment: lol, it was pretty easy. This solved my issue. Thank you so much. I'm so new to node.js, still too much to learn. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy to help. You'll need to read up on async stuff in JS, to understand how to work with Promises, async/await. But you've figured out quite a lot already!